# ng serve --open displaying error in ubuntu server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to angular CLI. I have worked in angular 1. I just angular cli using command `npm install -g @angular/cli` as given on there site [quick start guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) I also created my first project as per instruction give. But now when i try to run it using `ng serve --open` i am getting this error.

This is the error.

```
    `** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open 
    your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
    10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeinternal/child_process.js:325            
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

    Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:325:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:493:9)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/my-app/node_modules/opn/index.js:74:26)
    at Server.server.listen (/var/www/html/my-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:213:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1349:10)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
`
```

I tried by reinstalling angular and recreating the project but still getting error. Is there anything else i need on ubuntu. As i tried installing same project on mac there it worked fine.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the --open option?

Comment: Are you using `angular` or `angularJS`???? They are completely seperate yet both are tagged.

Comment: its permission issue ..

did u try sudo ?

Comment: @ParthGhiya yes i tried with sudo also but it was not working

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks it works when i run without --open . But i did not get what was the issue

Comment: @zze yes i am using angular

Comment: @VinitSingh can u try this `chmod +x node_modules/`

Comment: Why would you need angular cli to be installed globaly on a server at first? Just deploy the output of `ng build --prod` on your server and run that with `nginx` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: The issue seems to be that ng serve can't open the browser. Most probably because there is no browser on an  ubuntu server. Why would there be? And indeed, why do you run angular CLI on a server (unless it's your CI server, but even then, why do you try to open a browser)?

Comment: @JBNizet Even in case of CI sever there is no need to run cli globally anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet I am working on my personal ubuntu pc. I am just in learning phase in angular. Please put that in answer so that i can mark as correct answer. may be it will help other beginners also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but not on my server but on my laptop. The problem is that for whatever reason, Angular is not able to open the browser so you should remove the `--open` or `-o` option from your command. So remove the option and open the browser manually and navigate to `localhost:4200`.

But in your case, you need to actually use `ng build --prod` and deploy the dist folder in your server as you're publishing the project.